# How can i add multiple match conditions in a regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a String like this : `String x = "return function ('ABC','DEF')";`

I am using this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(formula);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("------> " + matcher.group();
}
```

to retrieve strings between single quotes.

My question is: how can i adapt this regex so that it will check for strings between single quotes AND strings  like " ,'DEF' " (meaning which start with ,' and end with ')?

Comment: Could you clarify your question with an example? "my input string is `exactly this string with 'quotes'` and my output string expected is `string 'quo` or whatever you are expecting...? Right now I am thinking you want to match (return) `ABC` and `DEF` - is that right? Or is it `'ABC'` and `'DEF'`?

Comment: why do you need '.*?' and not just '.*' ?

Comment: Also - please use backticks to make your code more legible, like this: `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'"); `

Comment: ok, sorry for the confusion. the output is ok if u use the regex i posted, i was wondering if i can "improve" that regex so that instead of searching for strings between quotes like 'quotes' it will look for strings like **,'string'** or **('string'**.

Comment: @Floris what do you mean?

Comment: @DanielV - you can use the backtick symbol \` to delimit a piece of code; this makes it appear `like so`. It is a great way to make your code examples more readable. Of course you can use the `{}` button when you edit your question to easily mark a block of code as `code`, too. Note - it's very hard to make the backtick symbol itself appear in your comment...

Comment: @Floris - ah, ok i got it now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
'[^']+'|"[^"]+"
```

Just to match with empty quoted string change '+' to '*'.

See [test](http://regexr.com?33k15).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regex pattern:

```
Pattern.compile(",?'(.*?)'");
```

`,?` means 0 or 1 commas. The ? is greedy, so if there is a comma, it will be included in the match.

**So:** This will match:

- A comma, followed by a string enclosed in single quotes
- OR.. only a string enclosed in single quotes

Answer (score 1):

This pattern should do what you want:

```
"(?:,\s*)?'[^']*'"
```

The `?` means the first group will match zero or one times.

I used `(?:...)` because this is a non-capturing group.  It is better to use when you don't need to capture that portion of the match.

Also, I replaced `.*?` with `[^']*`, meaning the single-quoted string contains anything that is not a single quote.  This is more efficient and less likely to lead to mistakes in your regex than `.*?`.

(Note: this regex allows there to be space between the comma and the start of the string.  At first looking at your example, I thought that was true of your example.  But now I see that it is not.  Still, that might be useful depending on what your data looks like).